# Forensics on ipad .img wont mount in Kali

Tags: kali-linux, forensics, ios

I am attempting to do some forensics on my iPad. [I am following along with this article from sans..](http://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/forensics/forensic-analysis-ios-devices-34092) on page 13 is the start of the Jailbreaking section...I would like to mount the image and then find the files listed on the following pages.

Model A1219...I did redsn0w 0.9.14b2 the iPad is not 3G and I don't have a passcode on it.

I installed openSSH and did

```
ssh root@192.168.1.120 dd if=/dev/rdisk0 bs=1M |dd of=ios-root1.img
```

I can't get it to mount though...or couldn't find anything when trying to use Scalpel

tried this

```
mount -t hfsplus -o ro,loop /media/psf/Home/ios-root1.img /mnt/hfs/
mount -t hfs /media/psf/Home/ios-root1.img /mnt/hfs/
mount -t hfsplus /media/psf/Home/ios-root1.img /mnt/hfs/
```

`dmesg | tail` gives me `hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using photorec

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk

sudo photorec
```

PhotoRec is an open-source data recovery software, created to restore lost files, photos and videos. It has been tested on the iPod touch and works like a dream. However, in order for it to work, your iPhone must be jailbroken. It needs access to locked files and the iPhone subsystem, which is locked on non-jailbroken iPhones.

Answer (score 0):

Using testdisk or SleuthKit's mmls find the partition offset and create separate partition images using dd.

That did the trick for me on an UFED imaged iPad (1st version)

Comment: (Without open source ttols) Using R-Stuido from RTT is simpler too...